# Why specify [0] when using new FormData()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I've just spent a good few minutes debugging `why new FormData($("#ImageEditorForm"));` isn't working. After turning to Stack Overflow, I found a suggestion in another thread to use `new FormData($("#ImageEditorForm")[0]);` instead.

I made the change, not expecting anything to happen. Instead, the code now works perfectly and as expected. Previously, nothing was being submitted to the server. Now, form data and files appear as expected.

My question is why is the "[0]" required? There is only one element with that ID in the DOM. Selecting by ID should surely return only one element? What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("#ImageEditorForm")` returns a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) and `FormData` requires a DOM Node.

You can use `document.getElementById(id);` which returns a DOM Node.

```
FormData(document.getElementById("ImageEditorForm"));
```

Or use `document.querySelector(selector);` which takes a css selector and returns the node if found and null otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 2):

When selecting with jQuery, the returned object is a jQuery object, and to get the actual DOM-node this represents, you use [0] on the jQuery object.

If you had used a selector which returned a couple of results, it would be easier to understand why you would need to index into the object to get to the actual DOM-node, but this is standard jQuery.

And as [andlrc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887539/andlrc) said, you need to pass an actual DOM-node to the FormData function.

Comment: Thank you for adding to the above explanation! I had not realised this - I assumed selecting with jQuery would return the same as document.getElementById().

Comment: @Ilmiont In your case using jQuery will return a jQuery object which contains a reference to the same DOM Node that `document.getElementById` returns.